# Compile with JDK-8 and run with JRE-11

Tags: java, compilation, runtime

The following code is successfully compiled with JDK-8 and runs successfully with JRE-8.

```
new SimpleDateFormat().parse("01.01.2000 00:00:00")
```

But with JRE-11 it throws:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date
```

This is the fix. It successfully compiled with JDK-8 and runs successfully with JRE-11:

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse("01.01.2000 00:00:00")
```

Is it a good idea to compile with JDK-8 and let it run with JRE-11?

Comment: sure, why not, as long as you're not trying to do it the other way aroundµ

Comment: Is it a good idea to compile with JDK-8 and let it run with JRE-11? - Yes. Is it a good idea to use constructors that use default values? - Not always as those defaults can change. Is it a good idea to use `SimpleDateFormat` and thus the olfd date api? - Not since Java 8 introduced the new api and even before that there was Joda time.

Comment: Note that your fix is still making a hardcoded assumption on date formats for your specific locale, so you should be passing in the expected format string too unless you are definitely writing dates with same `DateFormat.getDateInstance()` formatter. For example, `DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse("01.01.2000 00:00:00")` reports  `Unparseable date: "01.01.2000 00:00:00"` for my PC.

Comment: @Thomas, since I Agree on most things you said, Java 8 and 11 have a lot of difference. I would avoid. And for the question: The locale or date format could be different.

Comment: From [the documentation of the SimpleDateFormat constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#%3Cinit%3E()): “**Note:** This constructor may not support all locales. For full coverage, use the factory methods in the DateFormat class.”  (The [Java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat--) is the same.)